# .htaccess with virtual hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I decided to add virtual hosts on apache. My previous conf was:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain1.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>`

I have .htaccess in /var/www/ which was doing redirect for non-www to www and subdomain like forum.domain1.com to www.domain1.com/forum
This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.com/forum%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www..*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*).(com|com/)
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%1.%2{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now i have two domains and i setup virtual hosts using this tutorial:
[Virtual host on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

So, now in my /etc/apache2/sites-available i have 3 files, default, domain1.com and domain2.com. .htaccess stayed in /var/www/ and its working for domain1.com but it is not working for domain2.com.
Do i need to change .htaccess in /var/www/ to accept domain2 or i can add .htaccess to /var/www/domain2.com/public_html/ ? 
Do i need to move previous .htaccess from /var/www/ to /var/www/domain1.com/public_html?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have .htaccess in your www folder, you should put them in the vhost DocumentRoot and use each .htaccess to control each site individually.

so your tree should be:

```
/var/www/
 - domain1.com
   - .htaccess
 - domain.com
   - .htaccess
```

siteroot .htaccess files should only be used in exceptional circumstances, otherwise there is no point in using Vhosts... might aswell just have 1 vhost and let .htaccess do the rest.

Comment: I moved htaccess to vhost root but now my subdomains now working, only adding www...

Comment: in your vhost you have to create add `ServerName domain1.com`  then in your OS hosts file add this `127.0.0.1 domain1.com`

Comment: already added servername. added host but problem still exist...only adding www in front of url.

Comment: Ok, i found out that htaccess is working but my subdomains isnt working. i need to add in my vhost conf file new virtual names for subdomains. so i put ServerName sub.domain1.com DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/sub. it looks like htaccess point sub.domain1.com to /var/www/ even when i add ServerAlias *.domain1.com. Maybe someone will help this for subdomains in multiple virtual hosts.